# Why is window[func] undefined in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script that validates form fields. The form input has a data-validate attribute that contains a CSV of different functions. I loop through all inputs containing a data-validate value, separate those values into an array, and loop through that array to call the corresponding function.  My problem is that `window[func]` is undefined - I get "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" message. What am I doing wrong?  Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xr8ny1j/1/)

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" data-validate="min_length[4]">

(function($){
    var fields = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('[data-validate]').each(function(){
        var rules = $(this).data('validate').split("|");
        var label = $(this).parent().find('label').first();
        fields[i] = {
                name: $(this).attr("name"),
                label: label.text(),
                rules: rules,
                element: $(this)
        }
        i++;
    });
    $.each(fields, function(key, field){
        field.element.on('focusout', function(){
            $.each(field.rules, function(key1, rule){
                if(rule.includes("[")){
                    var rule = rule.match(/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/);
                    func = rule[1];
                    var len = rule[2];
                    params = [field.element.val(), len];
                } else {
                    func = rule;
                    params = [field.element.val()];
                }
                if(callFunc(func, params)){
                    field.element.addClass('is-valid').removeClass('is-invalid');
                } else {
                    field.element.addClass('is-invalid').removeClass('is-valid');
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

function min_length(str, len){
    return str.length > len;
}
function callFunc (func, arguments){
    window[func].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

Comment: Your error message says that `window[func]` is `undefined`. Not that `.apply` is `undefined`.

Comment: What is `func`?

Comment: You get `window[min_length]` there, which isn't a thing.  What do you expect there?

Comment: At least in your JSFiddle, your `min_length` function is not a global function, i.e. not a property of `window`. You can explicitly assign `window.min_length = min_length` to correct this issue, although the details will depend on how exactly your load this module. See this [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls3g6rL0/).

Comment: if func is not defined on global window object.. it will be undefined and you can't do a method call to undefined object...it will throw error

Comment: [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1838-wrapping-the-window-object-in-a-jquery-wrapper.htm) might help

Comment: @Bergi the func variable is the value of the function name I want to call.

Comment: check if `window[func]` exists and is a function before calling it. When it's not do some debugging to figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made it work with some improvements, check it out:

```js
(function($){
  window.min_length = function(str, len) {
   return str.length > len;
  }
  function callFunc(func, arguments){
      return window[func](...arguments);
  } 
 var fields = [];
 $('[data-validate]').each(function(){
  var rules = $(this).data('validate').split("|");
  var label = $(this).parent().find('label').first();
  fields.push({
    name: $(this).attr("name"),
    label: label.text(),
    rules: rules,
    element: $(this)
  });

 });

 $.each(fields, function(key, field){
  field.element.on('input', function(){
   $.each(field.rules, function(key1, rule){
    if(rule.includes("[")){
     var rule = rule.match(/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/);
     func = rule[1];
     var len = rule[2];
     params = [field.element.val(), len];
    } else {
     func = rule;
     params = [field.element.val()];
    }
    if(callFunc(func, params)){ 
     field.element.removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
    } else { 
     field.element.removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
    }
   });
  });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
input {
    outline: 0;
}
.is-valid {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.is-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="first_name" data-validate="min_length[4]">
```

Some issues:

1. You check the result of function `callFunc(func, params)` call but it
   returns nothing, i.e. `undefined`, so your condition is always
   `false`. You should return the result of `min_length()` from 
   `callFunc()`.
2. I found 2 classes `is-valid` in the css section of the snippet on
       jsFiddle. One of them should be `is-invalid`.
3. Also due to some closure issues it seems that your
       function `min_height` didn't become a property of `window`. So, I
       placed it inside the IIFE and explicitly added it to `window` which
       works because of closures, again.
4. There is no need for `i` variable - you can just `push()` objects
   into array.
5. Also it is possible to use `...` operator calling `min_length`
   inside `callFunc` instead of that `apply` thing.
6. Consider using [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of `focusout`.

Comment: I implemented your ideas which got rid of the error, but my min_length field always returns false. Have any idea why? I did convert the len param to a number like @Andy said in his answer.

Comment: Sounds strange. Note that you shouldn't splice arguments from 1st position. It is an array contaning a string and length from data-validate attribute. My jsFiddle and fiddle on SO work fine as I see. Update the initial fiddle or post a new  troubled one.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the specific error you're getting, I'm not getting that at all from your code. However, here's what I figured out with some testing (and fixed):

1) You need to `return` the value of the function you call in `callFunc` otherwise you'll just get `undefined`. In addition you're not passing in the right number of arguments.

```
return window[func].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
```

2) You need to convert your `len` parameter to a number from a string:

```
return str.length > Number(len);
```

3) Both of your classes are called `is-valid` :)

[Here's the full working code.](https://jsfiddle.net/jxng05Lx/3/)